# Install Ubuntu on a partition of secondary HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm bought a laptop with the following configuration:

240 GB SSD for Windows 10
1 TB HDD

I have some important programs and documents on the HDD and I don´t want to loose them. I have reserved 50 GB of space to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the seccondary HDD. [Current configuration of my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b6GL.png) . I would like to install ubuntu in the 50 GB partition in HDD 1 and leave the SSD in its current state. How would I do it?

Edit:

I'm not just trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a separate HDD, it must be on a partition of that HDD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu on D:\ drive partition as Dual-boot with windows 7 on a SSD C:\ drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679309/install-ubuntu-on-d-drive-partition-as-dual-boot-with-windows-7-on-a-ssd-c-d) and [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Be sure to also install grub2's boot loader to same drive as you are installing Ubuntu. Then you will not overwrite the Windows boot loader on the Windows drive. And in BIOS set it to boot Ubuntu. But if Windows needs repairs or fast start up turned off again after an update to Windows, you can directly boot it from BIOS. Grub only boots working Windows.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a full system backup
2. Boot From Ubuntu Disc/USB and choose:

   1. installation
   2. When you see <kbd>Installation Type</kbd> select *"something else"*
   3. on the next page Device for bootloader installation"1TB HDD".
   4. Make a ext4 `/` mounted partition
   5. click next.

That's all.

Comment: What about the information in the HDD? I don't want to loose it. I have some programs there

Comment: @EduardoAndrésCastilloPerera It's the boot sector only that will be changed and as long as you don't click on any "Delete" and take a full system backup before you start, there is 0 risk.