# How to Install Ubuntu on a pre-existing D drive?

Tags: dual-boot

Unlike [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679309/install-ubuntu-on-d-drive-partition-as-dual-boot-with-windows-7-on-a-ssd-c-d) question, I have **5**  already-formatted partitions (Each are "Logical" and "N.T.F.S" style) in the hard disk, and all are being used for specific type of documents. (C drive being used for Windows)

I want to install [Linux Ubuntu for desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/features)  on the **pre-existing drive D**; and without interfering any pre-existing partitions and their contents. I have downloaded the ISO file. Please guide me with flow charts.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/55441/install-ubuntu-on-a-ntfs-partition that you cannot install Linux into a pre-exisitng NTFS formatted partition due to permission issues.  It would not work.  You can look into something like WUBI, but you need to understand that it is no longer developed by Canonical so any support you need would have to go through the new maintainer of it.  See: https://www.lifewire.com/wubi-linux-installation-program-2201175

Comment: Omg then installing Ubuntu is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I dont know UEFI and other technical aspects of boot.

Comment: Look into using VirtualBox or WUBI.  The biggest difference is that VirtualBox will run in your windows without rebooting the OS so you can run a virtualized Ubuntu installation safetly.   WUBI installs into a file that gets mounted at bootup but does not require any partitioning of the drive as well.   With WUBI Ubuntu runs in its own space but it does require you to reboot your system to run.